# Alfresco upload and file creation issue

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am getting an error while creating a folder in alfresco and also while uploading a document to the repository. File uploading is failing by showing an orange colour process bar. Can someone please help me in resolving this?
I am posting the screenshot below.

[image: This is the error which i am getting while creating the folder]

[image: File uploading error]

Thanks,
Rajiv

Comment: please add error log of backend

Comment: Need to tell us specific version of Alfresco and whether or not you are running any customizations.

Comment: I am using alfrescp community 5.2. There are quite a few customizations.

Comment: There are no error in error logs. I am able to upload from server, but i am facing this issue when i try to upload from a LAN computer.